# Get newline characters from textarea

Tags: javascript, html

in text area line beaks are auto added when text is longer than textarea line, and question is how to get text from textarea with newline chars (those added by user and added by textarea)? please post example in jsfiddle.net

```
$(selector).val()
```

returns text with user newline character and it drops auto newline character which are needed

[my result so far](http://jsfiddle.net/7tzb9/3/)

here is a sample, additional newline character is needed between 'seven' and 'eight'

Comment: please create baseline of what you have tried i jsfiddle.net

Comment: I think you need to calculate the width of the text, because these breaks are virtual.

Comment: ok but for
    wrap="hard"
it works as I would like to but it's only for forms and I need it in JS variable...

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this:**

**html:**

```
<div id="fi"></div>
<textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
<button id="btn">go</button>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var btn = $('#btn');
    var txtarea = $('#txtarea');
    var result = $('#fi');
    btn.click(function() {
        var val = txtarea.val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
        result.html(val);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**or set no of rows**

```
<textarea cols='60' rows='8'>This is my statement one.&#13;&#10;This is my statement2</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have came up with this solution (it also restricts amount of characters in line and amount of lines)

[working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/q74vm/2/)

```
ttxt()
```

is a main method